# Почему не работает абсолютный путь в ajax-запросе на локальном сервере?

Tags: javascript

На локальном сервере лежит страница по адресу:

```
http://localhost/form/index.html
```

К странице подключен JS-файл:

```
http://localhost/form/shared/r.js
```

В JS-файле есть AJAX-запрос с абсолютным путем:

```
async checkMultiAuth() {
    const settings = await this.ajax({
      url: "https://domain.com/api/user/v1/settings?namespaces=MULTIAUTH",
    });

    if (
      settings &&
      settings.multiauth &&
      settings.multiauth.enabled &&
      settings.multiauth.host
    ) {
      const data = await this.ajax({
        url: "/multiauth/ping",
        host: settings.multiauth.host,
        options: {
          credentials: "include",
        },
      });

      if (data && data.result && data.result === "success") {
        this.redirectToSite();
      }
    }
  }
```

Но запрос не срабатывает, и в консоли выводится сообщение:

```
GET http://localhost/https://domain.com/api/user/v1/settings?namespaces=MULTIAUTH 403 (Forbidden)
```

В чем проблема? Почему к абсолютному адресу добавляется домен локального сервера?

Comment: А что такое this.ajax?